# how to get special characters like • correctly in the textview

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a text view in which i want to populate the text from a text file  but the problem is text file contains some special characters like Bullets(•  Appreciate )  and God’s which in the textview are appearing in very wierd way eg : •    Appreciate is coming as ? Appreciate and  God’s is coming as god?s  can some body help me in this how to get these special characters correcly in text view if niot correctly olease help in removing them

here is my code:-\

```
                    URL website= new URL(url);
                    URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            connection.getInputStream(),"UTF8"));

                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                    String inputLine;
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                        response.append(inputLine+"\n\n");
                    in.close();
                    description = response.toString();
```

Comment: what's your code look like now?

Comment: your encoding is off. how do you receive the data ?

Comment: URL website= new URL(url);
      URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        connection.getInputStream(),"UTF8"));

      StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
      String inputLine;
      while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
       response.append(inputLine+"\n\n");
      in.close();
      description = response.toString();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regexp` to clean all special characters.

For example to clear all bullets use this regexp

```
\\s*(\\w\\)|•)\\s*
```

Comment: can i replace the special characters??